# NetBeans : Unable to attach debugger (getting Connection refused error)

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, weblogic, remote-debugging

I am using Weblogic server and want to debug using the NetBeans IDE (v7.2)

In setDomainEnv.cmd, I have

```
if "%DEBUG_PORT%"=="" (
    set DEBUG_PORT=8453
)
set debugFlag = "true";

if "%debugFlag%"=="true" (
    set JAVA_DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=%DEBUG_PORT%,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% %enableHotswapFlag% -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole...
) else (
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% %enableHotswapFlag% -da
)
```

Then, in Netbeans, I go to Debug > Attach Debugger, enter all the details for 
Host, Port and Timeout

But I am getting Connection refused error.

Is there any way to enable debug settings from Weblogic console as well?

Comment: I also got the same error using glassfish server after a power failure I tried everything but nothing worked and i ended up uninstalling and reinstalling the server and finally it worked, I never got to know what was causing it though. As you await an answer you might to try the same.

Comment: When you start your server do you see `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453` in the terminal? If not (or just to give it a try), instead of putting those arguments in JAVA_DEBUG, put them all into JAVA_OPTIONS to see if that is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`set debugFlag = "true";`

with

`set debugFlag="true"` (with no ; and space), it should work

Comment: Thx a lot...I did try that now...But I am still getting connection refused error when I try to attach..I have verified the ports and all which I am giving...

Answer (score 0):

In weblogic.xml set fast swap to false.

```
  <fast-swap>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </fast-swap>
```